# Reverse for 'path' not found. 'function' is not a valid view function or pattern name?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to pass the argument to the function through the url. But I am getting an error as:

> Reverse for 'combodetails' not found. 'combodetails' is not a valid
> view function or pattern name.

urls.py:

```
app_name = "dashboard"
urlpatterns = [
      path('combodetails/<int:id>/', combodetails, name="combodetails"),
]
```

views.py:

```
def combodetails(request, id):
     print(id)
     return render(request, "dashboard/combodetails.html", context={})
```

.html:

```
 <a href="{% url 'dashboard:combodetails' model.id %}" class="icuwfbegb">
```

I have used the same method in other functions and they are working fine. But here I don't know what's happening.

In project.urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls', namespace="dashboard"),),
]
```

Comment: Is the `dashboard` on the `dashboard:combodetails` an `app_name`?

Comment: dashboard is the app_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have commented on some parts of code in the HTML file using html comment style i.e. `<!--  -->` where I have used URL without argument that's why I am getting errors. I have removed the commented section from my file and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'combodetails' model.id %}" class="icuwfbegb">
```

Comment: I have used namespace in project.urls and gives name as 'dashboard'.

Comment: I have changed the code as per my urls and project.urls.py